# My rendered photo has black dots on it

Tags: rendering

If you look to the right of the photo are the girl's arm it has black dots on it.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question

Comment: If you have a question please rephrase your post to read like one. If you want someone to do it for you then post it over at https://blenderartists.org

Comment: Please don't make all of your question depend on a link. Use the tools for this site to place images and state your question using the guidelines posted on the following link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour. If you add more information you have a better chance of getting better answers. Use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question and add more information on your settings, how many samples you are using, etc.

Comment: Who is girl from them?

Comment: I don't have a sampling tab I am in a diff version. Also yes this is a question.

Comment: @Skritter if you have more information to clarify your question please use the [edit] link (located at the bottom of your post) and modify the content of your post. The question can be re-opened.